# Contact form 7 doesnt send form

Tags: php, wordpress

I use plugin cf7 and use  **Multiline files upload for contact form 7** plugin too
I add this in form

```
 <div class="files-left">[multilinefile files  limit:2097152 filetypes:doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|pdf|png|jpg|jpeg|gif]</div>
```

and  this `[files]`  in the Mail File attachments

when i click `send` button the contact form shows what is loading, but it lasts forever, and without multilinefiles it works fine

Comment: Without Multilinefile plugin, the form works?

Comment: When i use 'file ' than that works and i add atachment file but i must use Multiline files plugin , es when i use multilinefile than it's display me `POST https://www.TEST.com/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/2505/feedback`  500

Comment: you can try with another plugin.

Comment: Which one i can use?

Comment: Try with this one. https://wordpress.org/plugins/drag-and-drop-multiple-file-upload-contact-form-7/

Comment: shows the same thing